# Pair response from api to asked question (asyncio)

Tags: python-asyncio

Im asking to an api like this:

I import a csv file to a list, the list is like this:

This is the list created with the csv

```
[{'Ticker': 'ABT', 'PrecioCedear': '19453', 'PrecioAccion': '', 'PorcentajeVarDolares': '0.48%', 'VarDolares': '0.51'}, 
{'Ticker': 'ADBE', 'PrecioCedear': '17238', 'PrecioAccion': '', 'PorcentajeVarDolares': '-0.32%', 'VarDolares': '-1.65'}, 
{'Ticker': 'ADI', 'PrecioCedear': '8718.5', 'PrecioAccion': '', 'PorcentajeVarDolares': '-0.89%', 'VarDolares': '-1.58'}, 
{'Ticker': 'AEM', 'PrecioCedear': '11539.5', 'PrecioAccion': '', 'PorcentajeVarDolares': '1.09%', 'VarDolares': '0.5'}]
```

Then i use the "Ticker" to create a new list with the Urls to ask to the API, like this:

```
for empresa in lista_de_empresas:
  url_cedears = 'https://clientapi_sandbox.portfoliopersonal.com/api/1.0/MarketData/Current?ticker=' + empresa['Ticker']+ '&type=CEDEARS&settlement=A-48HS&source=web&foo=bar'
  url_list_cedears.append(url_cedears)
```

A little example of this list is like this:

```
['https://clientapi_sandbox.portfoliopersonal.com/api/1.0/MarketData/Current?ticker=ABT&type=CEDEARS&settlement=A-48HS&source=web&foo=bar',
 'https://clientapi_sandbox.portfoliopersonal.com/api/1.0/MarketData/Current?ticker=ADBE&type=CEDEARS&settlement=A-48HS&source=web&foo=bar']
```

Then i ask to the api:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def fetch_all(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[fetch(session, url) for url in urls],return_exceptions=True)
        return results

cotizaciones = asyncio.run(fetch_all(url_list_cedears))
```

Here i have the answer, the data to all the Tickers i ask, like for example:

```
{'date': '2023-08-17T16:56:03-03:00', 'price': 32.73, 'volume': 119640, 'openingPrice': 33.2, 'max': 33.31, 'min': 32.64, 'previousClose': 33.06, 
'marketChange': -0.33, 'marketChangePercent': '-0.99%'}
```

so in the results i get all the data from all the Tickers together.

As you see the data dont says nothing about from who is... i mean, is from the Ticker "TMO"? is from "MSFT"?

I can know if it is a answer to TMO or MSFT for the order, i mean, i get the answer in order. And i already accomplish that.

But the thing is, i can pair the ticker with the data? I want to do this so, is more easy, more beauty to manage, it will be nice something like a nested dictionary (as an example):

```
{
"TMO": {'date': '2023-08-17T16:56:03-03:00', 'price': 32.73, 'volume': 119640,
 'openingPrice': 33.2, 'max': 33.31, 'min': 32.64, 'previousClose': 33.06, 
'marketChange': -0.33, 'marketChangePercent': '-0.99%'},
"MSFT": {'date': '2023-08-17T16:56:07-03:00', 'price': 38.0, 'volume': 273559,
 'openingPrice': 38.37, 'max': 38.43, 'min': 37.94, 'previousClose': 37.99, 
'marketChange': 0.02, 'marketChangePercent': '0.03%'}, 
}
```

What would be the way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an intermediate async function that will call `fetch`, get is result, and annotate the ticker.

That is plain Python:

```
...

async def myfetch(session, url):
    # do this or send the ticker as an argument here as well:
    ticker = url.split("ticker=")[1].split("&")[0]
    result = await fetch(session, url)
    result["ticker"] = ticker
    return result

async def fetch_all(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[myfetch(session, url) for url in urls],return_exceptions=True)
        return results

...
```

Attempt for the fact that due to using asyncio the calls are made concurrently, **and *order* cannot be guaranteed**: if you are currently trying to pair the tickers with the answers by order with this code, you are most likely getting some random results along the way.

Comment: "if you are currently trying to pair the tickers with the answers by order with this code, you are most likely getting some random results along the way." But with your code i can pair to the ticker? if not... there is no way? Thanks.

Comment: yes - this code annotates the ticker to the results of each request: it does not rely on order of request.